# Return to first element in foreach

Tags: c#, .net, collections, foreach

Say I move with foreach loop in some collection.

At some point (e.g. by 4th elem) I want to return to first element of this collection (to go through all the elements again)

How to do this?

**EDIT**

Solution in comment by @dlev + enumerator.Reset()

Comment: Do you have some code that you've written that would help clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: +1 - foreach loops are intended to prevent manual iteration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a for loop instead. Or a while loop.

Comment: Good, but it must be a foreach loop

Comment: @Saint `foreach` compiles down to a `while` loop anyway: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: And if it is IEnumerable (enumerator) instead of collection?

Comment: Then you simply enumerate it again from the begining.

Comment: @polishchuk: Then call [`IEnumerator.Reset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset.aspx) (assuming `Reset` is implemented).  Easy enough to do that in a `while` loop.

Comment: @Brian, Be accurate with `Reset`, they downvoted this solution :-)

Comment: @Saint "but it must be a foreach loop" - Why? This comment makes the question look like trolling.

Comment: @Henk Holterman I thought that I could not change the current form of the code, but after analyzing site from link 'dlev' I changed my mind. It works good.

Comment: Solution = comment @dlev + enumerator.Reset()

Answer (score 18):

Though this solution is inelegant, and plenty of people will tell you that it exposes you to all manner of danger, you can always just do:

```
Restart:
foreach(var item in things)
{
    DoSomething(item);
    if(WeShouldStartOver()) goto Restart;
}
```

That is easy, clear and correct. (A lot of people will reflexively tell you that gotos are the spawn of evil and always wrong. Those people might be confusing "inelegant" and "easily abused" with "morally wrong".)

If you're one of those people who thinks that gotos are always wrong, you can hide the goto. Mysteriously, when you spell "goto" as "while" and "break" it is no longer morally wrong!

```
bool loopTheLoop = true;
while(loopTheLoop)
{
    loopTheLoop = false;
    foreach(var item in things)
    {
        DoSomething(item);
        if(WeShouldStartOver())
        {
            loopTheLoop = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

That is much longer, has way more complicated control flow, and uses a data flag just for control flow, rather than for expressing the meaning in the business domain of the program. I would argue that all of those things are as bad as the "goto", but some people really like this sort of thing.

I personally would be inclined to refactor the loop into a helper method:

```
while(LoopTheLoop()) {}
...
// Returns true if we bailed early, false if we did not.
bool LoopTheLoop()
{
    foreach(var item in things)
    {
        DoSomething(item);
        if(WeShouldStartOver()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can you explain *why* you want to do this strange thing? Maybe there is a better way to do what you want. Because frankly, all these solutions are pretty bad.

Comment: Without more information from the OP, we cannot know whether the first example will return him to the first element.  We live in a multithreaded age, and underlying collections can change by the time you restart.

Comment: @hoodaticus: I am confused by your objection, in two ways. First, if the OP has a special condition -- if there is some threading concern, or dinosaurs are going to attack him if he uses "goto", or something -- then it is up to the OP to tell us about the special condition. Every single one of the several million answers on SO could be "wrong" if the original poster did not include relevant information in the question. It is reasonable to assume that no special conditions are relevant if none are given.

Comment: Second, to address your specific concern: how does your proposed multithreaded code know that it is safe to mutate the collection after the "break" and before the second "foreach" starts, and yet somehow managed to *not* mutate it *during* the "foreach"?  It is not legal to mutate a mutable collection while it is being iterated, so it is reasonable to suppose that it is *not* being mutated at any point during this whole operation, including the restarts. Do you have some mechanism in mind whereby another thread sneaks in and mutates the collection at *exactly* the legal time?

Comment: When you exit the foreach loop, Enumerator.Dispose is called, and the collection is no longer being iterated.  A context switch can and often will happen at that point, at which time it is possible for the underlying collection to be modified "legally".  You do a disservice to programmers trying to learn these extremely basic concepts when you ASSUME that they don't need to know about multithreaded scenarios and the gotchas therein.  As to your question about a mechanism: thread safe enumerables lock during enumeration.  -1.

Comment: @hoodaticus: And how does the code on the other thread know that Dispose has been called? What if there is no Dispose method? An enumerator is not required to implement Dispose, and even if it does, it is not required to signal another thread saying "I'm disposing now, go ahead with your pending edit".

Comment: Regarding your assertion that "threadsafe" sequences lock themselves when there is an outstanding enumeration: are you sure about that?  This seems like an **insanely dangerous** pattern. A lock should be taken out for as little time as possible, but arbitrarily much time may pass between the creation and the destruction of an iterator. All the code that runs between when a lock is taken and when it is released should be well-understood to ensure that locks are ordered correctly, but enumerations often yield to arbitrary external code. What you describe seems very unsafe.

Comment: Dispose is the perfect place to exit a read lock.  I don't see what's so insanely dangerous here, but then, there's no realistic way I'd see things on your level.

Comment: @hoodaticus: Consider a method "IE<T> W<T>(IE<T> ts, F<T, bool> p) { foreach(T t in ts) if (f(t)) yield return t);}". Suppose ts is your collection which locks itself upon creation of an enumerator. This thread now has a lock taken out. Suppose another thread is waiting on that lock and has taken a second lock. Suppose either the call to f() or *any of the code that runs in the code that is iterating over the lazily-computed results of W* causes the current thread to wait on the second lock. **How do you avoid this deadlock**?

Comment: I'm going to agree with Eric here.  If the question doesn't specifically mention a multi-threaded scenario it is somewhat foolish to think that answers should take into account every possible context switch as a bug.  If the OP desired a thread-safe solution (for some definition of thread-safe) he should have said so in 36 point bold font.  Also Eric, you can use `backticks` to display inline code in comments nicer.

Comment: Yes, I've come around.  Now if someone will edit this answer so I can remove my idiotic downvote...

Comment: +1 I really don't fear goto like the plague, and I think it's perfectly fine in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Don't think there is anything build in but how about...

```
bool tryAgian = false;
do
{
   tryAgian = false;
   foreach(var item in items)
   {
      //do something
      if(needToStartAgain)
      {
         tryAgain = true;
         break;
      }
   }
} while(tryAgain)
```

EDIT: Optimised

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that as far as I know.

Just use different loop, for example `while` where you can control the iterator and decide if you increase or descrease it etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0;i<YourCollection.Count ; i++)
{
    if(YouNeedToStartOver)
    {
        i=-1;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: May want to try again with that for loop

Comment: +1 for simplicity, though obviously this doesn't work if you don't have index-based access to your collection.

Answer (score 0):

Within a `foreach` you can only go to the next element with `continue` or step out of the loop completely. You would need to use the iterator directly.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something of this sort

```
   private static void LoopMethod()
        {
           i= 0;
            foreach (string str in jack)
            {
                if (i == 4)
                    LoopMethod();

                Console.WriteLine(str);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will not restart. It will just start another enumeration and will continue with the first one after the second finished.

Comment: @Jack7: Example: jack contains 8 strings: "1", "2", "3", ..., "7", "8". Assuming that the `if` is executed only once because of another condition, your code will output "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "6", "7", "8". Those last three digits are the problem. They shouldn't be returned.

Comment: @Daniel, that would not be the result

Comment: @musefan: You are right, the result would be "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "5", "6", "7", "8"

Comment: @Daniel, better, but not right yet. Try...

"1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4" ... all the way until the program crashes for a stack overflow exception

Comment: @musefan: Try reading my comment completely: "Assuming that the `if` is executed only once"...

Comment: @Daniel, ah yes, my mistake. Not really something you should be assuming with sample code though

Comment: @musefan: If the `if` condition is always executed, this will result in a SO-Exception, that's clear. I wanted to demonstrate that it is still wrong, even after that problem is fixed...

Comment: @Daniel, of course. And I agree with you. For some reason my last comment about assuming with sample code - for some reason I though you did the code post... a moment of confusion on my part, it will not happen again :D

Answer (score -3):

I would consider creating and using an Enumerator of the collection if I were you.

```
    using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
    {

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (SatisfyResetCondition(enumerator.Current))                          
                enumerator.Reset();
            Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't do this with a foreach loop over a collection, because when you use a foreach loop, you cannot get access to the Enumerator being used (it's hidden by the compiler - which is the whole point of the foreach loop!), and a collection does not necessarily have an indexer for direct access to the elements.

Even if you could, the interface contract for IEnumerator.Reset specifies that you do not have to implement Reset at all and can throw an exception instead.  This means you cannot guarantee, for all collections, that Enumerator.Reset will return you to the beginning of the collection.

So no, you can't do what you have asked in the question; it is impossible.

Comment: Not the voter, but your answer is not overly helpful as far as solving the problem. While you are entirely correct that he can't *rewind* the loop he's in, he can certainly *restart* it, as other answers demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Here's mine.  There is no way to necessarily return to the first element with the facts the OP has given us.  We have no knowledge of whether the collection can change or not, possibly in another thread, such that the first element cannot be reached again in any guaranteed manner.  I should downvote every answer here that ignored this basic fact.

Comment: As I noted in a comment to my answer, it is reasonable to assume that there is no multithreading going on here -- both because the original poster did not state that this was a multithreaded scenario, and because it is reasonable to suppose that multithreaded code is obeying the rules and not mutating a collection while it is being iterated. So let's leave multithreading out of it. It is also reasonable to assume that enumerating the same collection twice gives the same results unless otherwise stated.  But hey, let's go with it and examine your claim that this scenario is "impossible".

Comment: Suppose you have a collection which, when enumerated twice, gives different results. Let's furthermore suppose that the original poster wishes to enumerate this crazy collection *twice* and get the same results, even though the collection does not return the same results twice.  Is it really *impossible* to make an enumerable object that *can* be enumerated twice *and* agrees with the original sequence? If we can assume the sequence is finite then the sequence can be enumerated once and stored in a list, for example. If the sequence is infinite then things get a bit trickier.